# PHP: Create an excel table

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I need to create an excel table with help of php. Is that possible? The php code below creates and write to an excel file. I would like to create an excel table with the data, see picture below. I'm using PhpSpreadsheet (sorry I forgot to say that)

Edit: The code below uses library PhpSpreadsheet to ceate a excel file with some content.

I want to create an excel table:

1. The code works and create the content as the second picture below shows. This is NOT an excel table, just plain text in cells.
2. But that is not what I want. I want to be able to create the content as the first picture below shows. This is an excel table. When you create an excel table by hand you can choose colrs etc. I do not care about the colors. Excel add the column name and push the content down.
3. What I have tried is to add: $sheet->setAutoFilter('A1:B5'); to the code, but this does not create an excel table as shown in the third picture below.
4. So the question is: What do I need to add to the code above to be able to create the content as shown in the first picture below
5. The fourth picture below shows how to crate an excel table in excel (and this is what I want the php code to do)

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'A1');
$sheet->setCellValue('A2', 'A2');
$sheet->setCellValue('A3', 'A3');
$sheet->setCellValue('A4', 'A4');
$sheet->setCellValue('A5', 'A5');
//$sheet->setCellValue('A6', 'A6');

$sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'B1');
$sheet->setCellValue('B2', 'B2');
$sheet->setCellValue('B3', 'B3');
$sheet->setCellValue('B4', 'B4');
$sheet->setCellValue('B5', 'B5');
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('CreateExcelTable.xlsx');
```

The picture below show the tableI would like to create

[image]

With the code above this is created:

[image]

With the code added:
$sheet->setAutoFilter('A1:B5');

The picture below show what is created.It is not a table

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly is not working with the given code? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: Where is the file being saved? Could this be related to a write permission error? You haven't exactly specified what error is being thrown here or what you have tried so far to solve it.

Comment: _"I need to create an excel table with help of php. Is that possible?"_ - Well, what does the posted code do? You already seem to know about PhpSpreadsheet, so the question is very unclear. Do you get any errors? If you tell us what the actual problem is, we might be able to help.

Comment: Hello, there is no error in the code. I would like to create the table in the first picture. But I can not figure out how to do it

Comment: If there is no error in the code, what else is not working? Please clarify what the code **should** do, and what it currently doesn't do

Comment: Hello Nico, I would like the code to create the table as shown as the first picture above. The picture where you could see kolumn1/Kolumn2.  My code does not create that one, it creates the second picture above and my question is: What do I need to add to the code above to be able to ceate the table shown in the first picture above. Is it more clear?

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it. What exactly is missing? The coloring? Also, why do you put stuff in `A1` in the code that should be in `A2` according to the image?

Comment: Sorry Nico, I do not know how to more explain what I want the code to do.

Comment: The confusion comes from not knowing how Excel works, but trying to help nonetheless. A "Table" in excel terms is a special kind of object. It's not just a bunch of tabular data. It's closer to a named range (which PHPSpreadsheet can do) but adds SQL-lite functionality of referring columns by names and applies formulas across all rows.

The question was 100% clear, but it requires knowing about Excel (which should be expected from answers, too).

Answer (score 2):

Support for reading and writing Tables was added to PhpSpreadsheet [v1.23.0](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1230---2022-04-24). Here's what it would look like for the basic example you provided:

```php
<?php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Table;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Table\TableStyle;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Column1');
$sheet->setCellValue('A2', 'A1');
$sheet->setCellValue('A3', 'A2');
$sheet->setCellValue('A4', 'A3');
$sheet->setCellValue('A5', 'A4');
$sheet->setCellValue('A6', 'A5');

$sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Column2');
$sheet->setCellValue('B2', 'B1');
$sheet->setCellValue('B3', 'B2');
$sheet->setCellValue('B4', 'B3');
$sheet->setCellValue('B5', 'B4');
$sheet->setCellValue('B6', 'B5');
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

// Create the table
$table = new Table('A1:B6', 'Table1');

// Optional: apply some styling to the table
$tableStyle = new TableStyle();
$tableStyle->setTheme(TableStyle::TABLE_STYLE_MEDIUM9);
$tableStyle->setShowRowStripes(true);
$table->setStyle($tableStyle);

// Add the table to the sheet
$sheet->addTable($table);
        
$writer->save('CreateExcelTable.xlsx');
```

The result:

[image: Spreadsheet creating from the above code block]

You can find more complex examples in the [repository samples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/tree/master/samples/Table).

Answer (score 1):

Insert/Table is simply a GUI "shortcut" method for styling and setting autofilters against a block of cells. Both of these can be done as individual tasks using PHPSpreadSheet, but the library does not provide a "shortcut" way of doing this with a single method call.

Take a look at [section](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/autofilters/) of the Developer documentation.

Comment: This is a common misconception. Tables are a whole different beast than named ranges and seem similar because they're both a way to treat a selection of data differently.

Tables definitively cannot be one in PHPSpreadsheet, and if creating them is a requirement then the current version CANNOT fulfill it to the best of my knowledge. With shortcuts or otherwise.

It can keep named ranges at spreadsheet level, but that may not be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem.
My Excel Template had some **array formulas** that refer to **Named Data Tables**,
(instead of writing in the array formula A2:A150 i would simply write NameOfMyTable[NameOfColumn])
When i inserted some data in my template using PhpSpreadSheet and downloaded the produced excel file, Each instance of NameOfMyTable[NameOfColumn] was replaced with **REF!**

Instead of searching how make or preserve **Named Data Tables** while using PHPSpreasheet. I simply converted all my Named tables back to simple ranges. (you can easily do this conversion through TableTools in excel without having to change every formula in your Excel Template).

Answer (score -1):

I have a code I wrote, use it if you want

[look at the code](https://github.com/diloabininyeri/dilovel/blob/master/src/Components/File/ExcelExport.php)

using

```
$excelExport = new ExcelExport(['name' => 'dılo'], 'file');
$excelExport->download();
```

shortest excel creation example with php

basic example

```php
<?php
$file="demo.xls";
$test="<table  ><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>";
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
echo $test;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I can not see that the code creates an excel table?

Comment: run on  browser ,you will see

Comment: can you make a simple example as my example above? That would be great!

Comment: I don't know which library you are using, but this is the easiest thing to give to the HTML table screen and added to the header 


 header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.xlsx');
 header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

Comment: ı edited an example...look at the up

Comment: I do not have an HTML table. The data comes from an SQL table and I would like to create an excel table as above.

Comment: As far as I see, the given code from the second snippet does not create an Excel file

Comment: Thanks, but the code does not create anexcel table as shown above (or I can not get it to create one)

Comment: This response ignores several things, which is why it's confusing everyone.
It does NOT create an excel file. It creates an HTML table that Excel happens to be able to open. This is a useful not questionable hack, as it tricks Excel but steps around several Excel convenienves (like storage of decimals and dates, which become hardcoded and cause problems when sharing these files).

It also ignores the original question. A "table" in Excel is a special type of object. It's a named range on steroids with its own functionality, not just a bunch of tabular data.